# Is Kotlin enough to integrate Stripe into my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am a beginner and have been coding in Kotlin for Android.
I need to integrate Stripe Connect into my app now but feel lost. When going through the Android documentation in Stripe, it mentions lines of code in `curl`, or sometimes in Ruby/Python/Php/Node/Go.

I don't know any of these. Do I need to learn another language to integrate Stripe? Is there something I'm missing? I get stuck at these parts as I don't know how to continue.

[This](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/standard) is the part of the documentation I'm trying to read through.

THe documention also recommends that I `create this Customer at the same time you create your user on your own backend` but doesn't show how to.

Any guidance would be appreciated. It seems to be good documentation if you already know what you're doing but as a beginner I'm lost.

Comment: My understanding is that you will need a server side component under your control. Related: https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend

Comment: As @MorrisonChang said, you need a server side component that can perform actions on your Stripe account via your secret API key. Your app should only use your publishable key for security reasons. You could check out the Stripe example app to see how they implemented a backend for a mobile app: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides

Comment: thank you guys, will look into it. So far I've been using Firebase for all my back end needs. Is that something I can achieve with Firebase too? Or that's not part of the services provided by them?